# In a Javascript Array, should a value be checked for before being removed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Conceptual question here, when using Javascript to remove an item from a collection by value, what is the more performant way to achieve this?

Assuming:

```
function arrayRemove(arr, value) {   
   return arr.filter(function(ele){       
      return ele != value;
});

var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

is simply using

```
var result = arrayRemove(array, 'b');
```

More appropriate than checking for its existence beforehand

```
if (array.includes('b')) 
    var result = arrayRemove(array, 'b');
```

The first is cleaner and less operations, but the later will not always trigger the filter.

Comment: both options will require iterating the entire array, hence it's not really "less operations" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JS perf for this. Looks like just calling the `arrayRemove` function before checking if the value exists, is better.

A simple test:

```
const arr = Array(10000000).fill(Math.random());
arr[10000] = 'e';

let start = Date.now();
const arr2 = arr.filter(v => v !== 'd');
console.log('filter time', Date.now() - start); // --- filter time 1168ms

start = Date.now();
if (arr.includes('e')) {
  console.log('includes time', Date.now() - start); // --- includes time 1ms
}
```

So as you can see if the array is really big if would be much faster

https://jsperf.com/js-array-filter/1

Answer (score 1):

I'd say `var result = arrayRemove(array, 'b');` is better, because this:

```
if (array.includes('b'))
```

will iterate over the array, and if it finds `b`, then this:

```
var result = arrayRemove(array, 'b');
```

will iterate over the array again to remove it, so you have two iterations if the element exists, and one if it doesn't. Using `arrayRemove(array, 'b')` directly will iterate only once in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Better to do with inbuilt methods provided `splice()` 
This method used to adds/removes items to/from an array and will return the removed item(s) from an array.
you can learn more about Splice here.
[Splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: IMO using `Array.filter` is best. `Array.splice` would require you to first get the index to remove (more than likely some iteration needs to be ran to get the index), then once you have the index, you can remove. `Array.filter` will do it in a single iteration

Answer (score 0):

I will go with **not checking for its existence beforehand** because `.filter` takes care of the values not present in the array. However if not doing the `.filter` and trying to iterate the array for particular key value operation using `for` or `while`, it is good practice to check the existence of the value.

```js
function arrayRemove(arr, value) {
  return arr.filter(function(ele) {
    return ele != value;
  });
}
  var arry = ['a', 'c', 'd'];

  console.log(arrayRemove(arry,'b'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.filter function creates a new array - so it's always will consume more resources then if.

A simple test:

```
const arr = Array(10000000).fill(Math.random());
arr[10000] = 'e';

let start = Date.now();
const arr2 = arr.filter(v => v !== 'd');
console.log('filter time', Date.now() - start); // --- filter time 1168ms

start = Date.now();
if (arr.includes('e')) {
  console.log('includes time', Date.now() - start); // --- includes time 1ms
}
```

So as you can see if the array is realy big if would be mutch faster